# Assigning return value of JS function to a variable is failing with an error

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a simple HTML document and JS file and I cannot figure out why this simple code is not working.

Here's the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function getStatus() {
            alert('test 1');
            var isOnline = isOnline();
            alert('test 3');
        }

        function isOnline() {
            alert('test 2');
            return true;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>getStatus();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It only displays the "Test 1" alert, and then nothing. If I remove the `isOnline()` function call, it will display the "Test 1" alert followed by the "Test 3" alert without issues. I'm receiving `Uncaught TypeError: isOnline is not a function` in the browser console.

[Browser console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkXNX.png)

**UPDATE:**

Turns out it was due to the fact that I named my variable with the same name as my function. I am new to JavaScript and was unaware of this restriction.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o8ge4m3d/ Cannot reproduce, but check your console for errors

Comment: Whats the error message you are getting in your console?

Comment: There's no error in your code.It works fine

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error from the browser console to the question. It says:
Uncaught TypeError: isOnline is not a function

Comment: I removed a few things when sharing the code here, and turns out I removed an important piece. If you assign the return value of the `isOnline()` function to a variable it causes the error. That's why nobody was able to reproduce, I didn't think that would be relevant. I updated my question with that detail.

Comment: Turns out it was due to the fact that I named my variable the same name as the function. I am new to JavaScript and did not know this was not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that I named my variable with the same name as my function.

Answer (score 1):

It is successed.

http://jsfiddle.net/humskoa3/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getStatus() {
                alert('Test 1');
            isOnline();
                alert('Test 3');
                }

                function isOnline() {
              alert('Test 2');
                }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>getStatus();</script>
</body>
```

Why not?

again test!

Answer (score -1):

Usually alert can be done once for every interaction. Although I tried your code using chrome devtools and it works. It can be because your html file reads your js file as to alert once then finish function.

```
function getStatus() {
alert("1");
isOnline();
alert("3");
}
function isOnline() {
alert("2");
}
getStatus();
```